# How to change java runtime version in heroku app

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot app that uses JDK 11 but when Building on the Heroku it installs OpenJdk 1.8 :

```
-----> Uploading build...
       - success
-----> Deploying...
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/jvm
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 106.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v14
```

Although i created a 'system.properties' file in the root of the project and commited it to git `java.runtime.version=11` but it still installing OpenJdk 1.8 and not 11.

and this is the exception from the Heroku Cli :

```
2022-10-23T18:03:37.124247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-23T18:03:37.127120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-23T18:03:41.139758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar SeniorCare-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  $JAR_OPTS`
2022-10-23T18:03:42.062965+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-10-23T18:03:42.069472+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2022-10-23T18:03:42.544439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-23T18:03:42.646566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408259+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: dsi/senior/SeniorCareApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408398+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408445+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408507+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408597+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408637+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408674+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408712+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408768+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408826+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408878+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408940+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.408997+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.409054+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.409099+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.409161+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.409220+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.409255+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
2022-10-23T18:03:42.409297+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Comment: What did you put inside the `system.properties` file?

Comment: java.runtime.version=11 and i tried java.runtime.version=zulu-11

Comment: Then the only guess I have is that "root of the project" is not the same as root of the repository. It's either that or you have found a rather major bug in Heroku - considering how central it is to be able to change java version I think that's really unlikely to be the case.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Heroku uses JDK 1.8 for Java Apps.

You can change this by specifying your Java Runtime version in the `system.properties` file.

```
java.runtime.version=<jdk_version> (e.g. 11)
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.codejava.net/heroku/change-java-version-for-apps) for more.

Comment: I have followed all these steps but it is not working...